# How to show line numbers of text file opened in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Is there anything which will show line numbers for all the files opened in Visual Studio?

Comment: chose: Tools=>options=>Text Editor. Then you can select C# or css or HTML ...end check Line numbers.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VS 2010, for text only...

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Plain Text -> General -> Display Line Numbers
```

For everything...

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> General -> Display Line Numbers
```

Answer (score 3):

Browse to the following path:

> Tools -> Options -> Text Editors -> All Languages

Now **check** the option **Line Numbers**

And here you go!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages. Check "Show line numbers"

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your version of Visual Studio, but in VS2012 you must go to TOOLS -> Options -> Text Editor -> Plain Text then you must tick the "Line Numbers" Checkbox under the "Display" heading.